# Unique number/ID in each URL Title Field

Tags: url, title

Is it possible to auto insert a unique number/ID in each URL Title Field? For example:

Title: "article of the day"
URL Title: article-of-the-day-123

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

EE will do this automatically if you publish an entry with a title already in that channel.

Comment: Up to 50, IIRC. After that, it will throw an error.

Comment: Thanks but I would like to have EE do it even for non-duplicated titles. Is that possible? I can't have the ID in the title though, I need it only in the URL-title.

Comment: No ideas here - there are a couple of add-ons on Devot-ee that help manipulate titles and url titles but neither of them look to work with the current version of EE, and support in either case looks dicey.

Not sure what the goal is here anyway?

Comment: Well this request is coming from SEO people - apparently in order to submit articles to Google News, they have to have 3 unique numbers in the URL. If you know any other way of having 3 unique numbers (without having to manually put them) in the URL title, please do suggest :)

Comment: I think you have just crossed into 'custom add-on required land'...;